# How to align side text and table horizontally in R-markdown

Tags: text, r-markdown, position

As I am still an R-beginner I am using the tutorial:

https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html#position

My code below offers me the possibility to write a whole paragraph beside the table, but I fail at adding just one or two simple lines centered around the middle of the table. How can I position the short text so that it is horizontally centered to the table?

```
kbl(Haftungseinschätzung_table) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = F, position = "float_right") %>%
  column_spec(column = 1, width = "auto") %>%
  column_spec(2:5, extra_css = "text-align: right;") %>%
  row_spec(0, extra_css = "border-bottom: 2px solid #000;") %>% # Add gridline at the top of the table
  row_spec(5, extra_css = "border-bottom: 2px solid #000;")
```